# __LP64__ on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, predefined-variables

I know Windows uses LLP instead of the LP data model, but is there a predefined variable or something? on OS X/Linux you can use `__LP64__`.

Answer (score 6):

One way to check is with `_WIN64`, which is defined only on 64-bit Windows (see [here](http://predef.sourceforge.net/preos.html#sec24) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx)).  For example:

```
#if defined(__LP64__)
// LP64 machine, OS X or Linux
#elif defined(_WIN64)
// LLP64 machine, Windows
#else
// 32-bit machine, Windows or Linux or OS X
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if such variable, but you can test for `_MSC_VER`, which will be defined in Visual Studio. You can then assume an LLP model. If that ever changes in the future, you can use the value of `_MSC_VER` to test against compiler versions.

If you're looking for standard sized types, check out [boost::integer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/integer/index.html), which defines fixed-bit-sized integer types.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this won't disambiguate between 32-bit and 64-bit Windows, only between MSVC and other compilers (and between MSVC versions).

Boost seems overkill if this is the only reason for adding it as a dependency for the project.  If it's already being used, well, that's cool too.

Comment: @mrkj: Boost isn't all or nothing. Just grab the necessary header and live free.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a preprocessor variable (depending on the case, it might be required, but you may also be able to do without)? Is `sizeof(long) == sizeof(void*)` not good enough?

Comment: @pavel - This is a cross platform app that runs on OS X, Linux and Windows and moving to 64-bit and some Snow Leopard specific items, The logic would certainly be a lot easier to integrate if there was a preprocessor variable. I could use _Win_32 and _Win_64 I suppose since those wont be defined on OS X where LP64 is...

Comment: The reason why I asked is because a lot of conditional compilation logic in C++ doesn't really require a preprocessor - you can creatively use templates to produce typedefs, for example. Or just use some stock things, such as `cstdint` header from Boost (as MSVC doesn't have it), and `intptr_t` when you need an integral type that has the same size as pointer on a given platform. It all depends on what specific cases are there in your code that are bitness-specific.

Comment: on 64-bit Windows `long` is 32 bits while `void*` is 64 bits. The same to [x32-ABI](https://sites.google.com/site/x32abi/) on Unix